# How to run GitHub project in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I try to run this code in my own computer: https://github.com/ThaiPham27/Depression_Detection_DNN

I've downloaded the zip file but I have no idea how can I run this code in Jupyter notebook and get the output. I couldn't find any complete guide for that.\

I have Python 3.9 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can only run notebook file on Jupyter Notebook, and the extension of notebook files is ".ipynb"

And you need to have jupyter notebook on your system, or you can download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)  package for that.

**P.S:** I also briefly looked into the notebook, seems like it was setup for Google Colab as it is using some CSV from google drive.